# Taking the Limit of Stars and Bars

Tags: probability, combinatorics, limits, solution-verification

I'm current working on the following question from Chapter 1 of *Theory of Probability and Random Processes* by Koralov and Sinai:

> For integers $n$ and $r$, find the number of solutions of the equation $$x_1 + \ldots + x_r = n,$$
> where $x_i \geq 0$ are integers.
> Assuming the uniform distribution on the space of the solutions, find $P(x_1=a)$ and its limit as $r\to \infty$, $n\to\infty$, $n/r\to\rho > 0$.

So, the first part is just a simple stars and bars and we get $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$. However, it's the second part, taking the limit, that I'm struggling with. Essentially, I'm trying to evaluate the following limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty\,r\to\infty\\n/r\to\rho} \binom{n-a+r-2}{r-2}\big/\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}.$$

Intuitively, I expect the limit to converge to some Poisson Distribution parameterized by $\rho$ and evaluated at $a$. I've attempted this by applying Stirling's Approximation, but have no idea how to proceed:

\begin{align}P(x_1=a)&=\binom{n-a+r-2}{r-2}\big/\binom{n+r-1}{r-1} \\ &= \frac{(n-a+r-2)!(r-1)!n!}{(r-2)!(n-a)!(n+r-1)!} \\ 
&= \frac{(r-1)n!(n-a+r-2)!}{(n+r-1)!(n-a)!} \\
&\approx \frac{(r-1)\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n\sqrt{2\pi (n-a+r-2)}\left(\frac{n-a+r-2}{e}\right)^{n-a+r-2}}{\sqrt{2\pi(n+r-1)}\left(\frac{n+r-1}{e}\right)^{n+r-1}\sqrt{2\pi (n-a)}\left(\frac{n-a}{e}\right)^{n-a}} \\
&\,\,\vdots \\
&= (r-1)n^n (e^{r-1})(n-a+r-2)^{n-a+r-2}(e^{2-r})\left(\frac{1}{n-a}\right)^{n-a}\left(\frac{1}{n+r-1}\right)^{n+r-1} \\
&\,\,\vdots \\
&= (r-1)e\left(\frac{n}{n+r}\right)^a \\
P(x_1=a)&= (r-1)e\left(\frac{n/r}{n/r+1}\right)^a.
\end{align}

Then, taking the limit of the last expression we get $(r-1)e(\rho/(\rho+1))^a$, which then goes to infinity. But this result makes no sense...

Comment: The elided steps seem to involve taking limits, not just equalities. The upper ellipsis seems OK (you just took the limit of the ratio of the square roots), but perhaps you should spell out more of the lower one. Generally speaking, I find it easier, less error-prone and also typographically more convenient to take logarithms before approximating quotients of Stirling’s approximations.

Comment: I’ve only ever seen this called stars and bars. But I like this name better. But please answer….: do they break your bones?

Comment: I think "Stars & Bars" is more common [[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) ]] & there are other names , @RougeSegwayUser , though "Stars & Bars" is nicely rhyming too !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can get a reasonable result without Stirling...

$${n-a+r-2\choose r-2}\big/{n+r-1 \choose r-1}$$

$$=\frac{(n-a+r-2)!}{(n-a)!(r-2)!}\cdot{\frac{n!(r-1)!}{(n+r-1)!}}$$

$$={\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-a+1)(r-1)}{(n+r-1)(n+r-2)\cdots(n+r-(a+1))}}$$
So in our limit, as $\{n,r\}\rightarrow \infty$, we have;

$$\approx\frac{(n)^{a}r}{(n+r)^{a+1}}=\frac{(r\rho)^{a}r}{(r\rho+r)^{a+1}}=\frac{(\rho)^{a}}{(1+\rho)^{a+1}}$$